# Android первый запуск приложения

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragment

Нашел в интернете кучу примеров с Navigation component из android jetpack, как переключаться между фрагментами и как при помощи sharedpreference отловить первый запуск.
Но как мне только при первом запуске, один раз показать первый фрагмент, а при втором и последующих запусках второй фрагмент, я не нашел ни где. У меня получилось так, но все кто видел этот код сказали, что он ужасен, толком не дав пояснений в чем его ужасность и как, это исправить. Был бы благодарен, если бы получил пояснения что ИМЕННО в нем ужасно. Я только начинаю, по этому плохо понимаю архитектуру и как правильно писать подобное.

Код Activity

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    var sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences? = null
    var sharedEditor: SharedPreferences.Editor? = null
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE)
            sharedEditor = sharedPreferences!!.edit()
            if (isFirstStart()) {
                supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .setReorderingAllowed(true)
                    .add(R.id.fragment_container_view, FirstStartFragment::class.java, null)
                    .commit()
            } else {
                supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .setReorderingAllowed(true)
                    .add(R.id.fragment_container_view, SecondStartFragment::class.java, null)
                    .commit()
            }
        }
    }

    private fun isFirstStart(): Boolean {
        return if (sharedPreferences!!.getBoolean("firstTime", true)) {
            sharedEditor!!.putBoolean("firstTime", false)
            sharedEditor!!.apply()
            true
        } else {
            false
        }
    }
}
```

Код фрагментов не стал приводить, так как в данном примере он не несет смысла. Мне нужно понять, как правильно реализовать "отлов" первого запуска приложения и в зависимости от этого показывать первый или второй фрагмент

Comment: Код норм, не понятно только как у вас в sharedPreferences true появляется и зачем вы его потом на false меняете. При таком подходе первый фрагмент будет появляться через раз.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja имхо код не норм, всему этому там не место вовсе

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На самом деле хранить состояние приложения в sharedPreferences не так и ужасно. Скорее речь об архитектуре. Например все действия с sharedPreferences необходимо выносить в отдельный класс и общаться с ним через ViewModel. Ваша активити должна заниматься только отображением контента, а логика должна быть во viewModel. В данном примере, что должно быть

```kotlin
- override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        if (viewModel.isFirstAppStart()) {
            // запустить стартовый фрагмент
        } else {
           // запустить второй фрагмент
        }
}
```

Вот пример вынесеного sharedPreferences в отдельный пакет src/preferences

```kotlin
private const val FILE_NAME = "appState.pref"
private const val IS_FIRST_RUN = "isFirstRun"

@Singleton
class AppStatePrefs @Inject constructor(
    @ApplicationContext context: Context
) {

    private val sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    private var _isFirstRun: Boolean = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(IS_FIRST_RUN, true)

    var isFirstRun: Boolean
        @Synchronized
        get() = _isFirstRun
        @Synchronized
        set(value) {
            _isFirstRun = value
            sharedPreferences.edit()
                .putLong(IS_FIRST_RUN, value)
                .apply()
        }

}
```

Обратите внимание на то, как вынесены имя файла и ключ. В этом классе можно хранить например все, что касается состояния приложения, что пользователь уже видел и т.д.
Вы можете заметить аннотации @Singleton @ApplicationContext. У вас этого не будет, это hilt, библиотека для внедрения зависимостей. Другими словами в приложении будет только один экземпляр этого класса, а значит мы можем из двух мест ассинхроно записывать поле isFirstRun, его гетер и сеттер нужно синхронизировать @Synchronized. Что бы пока один поток или корутина очищает значение,  мы не посмотрели туда с другого места.

Ознакомтесь с внедрением зависимостей, можно сразу приступить к hilt

ViewModel, если кратко, вот так она может выглядеть в вашем случаи

```kotlin
class MainViewModel @ViewModelInject constructor(
        private val appStatePrefs: AppStatePrefs,
        // тут ваши репозитории и sharedPreferences
) : BaseViewModel() {
    // методы доступа
    
    fun isFirstAppStart(): Boolean {
        return appStatePrefs.isFirstRun
    }

}
```

Comment: Ответ конечно верный, но автор с MVC не смог с ходу разобраться, а тут ему и MVVM и DI и в нагрузку многопоточную синхронизацию :) Это да, либо научится плавать, либо утонет.

Comment: Кстати о синхронизации. Подразумевается, что все вызовы `isFirstRun` будут из UI-thread, поэтому она тут как по мне лишняя.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja почему же только из UI-thread ? Вот пример из жизни, я хожу на сервер за курсом валют, естейственно ассинхроно записываю новое значение. Это был простой не потокобезопасный List. Мы делали `_balance.clear(); _balance.addAll(value)` При этом раз в год приложение ходило смотреть в гетер и попадало когда `_balance.clear()`. Я по моему могу в корутине выбрать main dispatcher, но он не гарантирует именно UI-thread.

Comment: Мы же не о вообще, а конкретно о `isFirstRun` и фрагментах автора.

Comment: Если не ошибаюсь, @Synchronized не всегда для корутин обеспечит безопасность. https://habr.com/ru/company/funcorp/blog/528778/

Comment: @Vlad Orlinskas  main thread и Ui thread одно и то же в Андроиде, и Dispatchers.Main будет работать на главном потоке (UI)

Comment: @IR42 ну первым предложением вы совсем решили припозорить меня. Хотя действительно я почему-то решил, что Dispatchers.Main не гарантирует главный поток (UI). Спасибо за уточнение.